# How do I remove TinyMCE text format

Tags: theme-development

I just want to get rid of all the text format options in WP text editor, like H1, H2, etc. Typing the post/page title automatically gives you a H1 heading. It's not good practice to have more than one H1 heading per post/page so there's no need for this option.

Let's say I just want to have an option for a subtitle like Heading 5 and nothing else. How do I do that?

Appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) is what you're looking for.